# Search for matrix spectrum

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

One task asks to find the spectrum of the matrix
$$
\left( \begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
-21&6&2&-20&-6\\
-21&12&-7&-14&-7\\
-2 &1&-4&-1&-1\\
19&-6&-2&18&0\\
0&7&-7&7&-2\\
\end{array} \right).
$$
I can find this spectrum using a computer, however, the task involves searching with a pen and paper. How is this possible? Do I really need to solve the fifth degree equation $det (A-\lambda I)=0$ analytically? Or is there some secret here that I don't know?

Comment: This is feasible by "killing" coefficients by subtracting/adding multiple rows and columns. Then we develop by rows or columns.

Comment: Presumably you are given some other input/hint, no?

Comment: The characteristic polynomial which is $-(x - 5) (x + 2)(x + 3)(x^2 - 3x + 32)$ has simple roots. It is easy to find it with a computer, but by hand ?